# How to check the output of an inner function in the outer function without an unbound local error?

Tags: python

I'm working on my first calculator in python, and I need a method of storing the input of the inner function so that when I run the outer function again, it will check the result to see if it's already been run.

```
power_on = True

def calculator():
    num_1 = float(input("What is the first number?\n"))
    operation = input("What is the operation?\n")
    num_2 = float(input("What is the second number?\n"))
    if result != None:
        num_1 = int(result)
        operation = input("What is the operation? \n +, -, *, / \n")
        num_2 = float(input("What is the second number?"))
    def calculate():
        if operation == "+":
            return num_1 + num_2
        elif operation == "-":
            return num_1 - num_2
        elif operation == "*":
            return num_1 * num_2
        elif operation == "/":
            return num_1 / num_2
        else:
            return "Invalid operation"
    result = calculate()
    print(f"{num_1} {operation} {num_2} = {result}")
    usercont = input(f"Would you like to continue operating with {result}? \nEnter Y to continue, enter N to restart\n")
    if usercont == "N":
        result = None

while power_on == True:
    calculator()
```

As you can see, this will generate an unbound local error because we're checking whether `result` has a value or not before we get a value from the inner function. The issue is that I have no way to correct this error without overwriting whatever the result actually is... if I assign `result = ""` under `def calculator()` then I solve the error but never retain my value.

I know this is a noob question but I would appreciate any help for figuring this out.

Thank you.

Comment: One thing that can make your code more clear: `calculate()` should be defined _outside_ `calculator()` and then only _called_ inside `calculator()`. That will make it easier to see the scope of each function. Beyond that, pass the `operation` and numbers  in as arguments to the `calculate()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the `result` variable outside of a loop and initialize it to `None`, you can reference that when choosing to ask about `num_1` or not.

like this:

```
power_on = True

def calculate(operation, num_1, num_2):
    if operation == "+":
        return num_1 + num_2
    elif operation == "-":
        return num_1 - num_2
    elif operation == "*":
        return num_1 * num_2
    elif operation == "/":
        return num_1 / num_2
    else:
        return "Invalid operation, dicklicker"

def calculator(power_on):
    result = None  # starts off with no result
    while power_on:
        if result is None: 
            num_1 = float(input("What is the first number?\n"))
        else:
            num_1 = int(result)

            
        operation = input("What is the operation?\n")
        num_2 = float(input("What is the second number?\n"))
        result = calculate(operation, num_1, num_2)
        print(f"{num_1} {operation} {num_2} = {result}")
        usercont = input(f"Would you like to continue operating with {result}?"
                         " \nEnter Y to continue, enter N to restart\n")
        if usercont == "N":
            result = None

calculator(power_on)
```

I cleaned up a little bit to make it more readable also.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Didn't really think to make two separate functions, but this is a more elegant and readable solution. Also I apologize for the random profanity in the code, weird habit of mine and I forgot to take it out.